# window.location.hash does not work after domain redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, hosting

When the webpage is loaded I use window.location.hash to add imformation to the URL. Since I bought a domain name redirecting to my server IP it is not working anymore. Only the domainname.com is displayed. Although the hash operation is performed. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using proper domain hosting.

Instead of pointing the domain at the IP address of your server (and configuring the web server to support Virtual Name Hosting if you are dealing in multiple sites there) you are letting your Domain Registrar point the domain at *their* server where they provide a simple web page consisting of a frame (this is known as "Domain Forwarding", "Domain Masking" or "Yuck").

When you set `location.hash`, you are setting the location of the frame, not the window.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all that stuff, I tried window.location.hash and location.hash. So how can I add something?

Comment: You stop using domain forwarding and use real domain hosting.

Comment: ah, yeah it worked, but now the IP is shown instead of the domain name. Can't I have both domain name + hash?